# Angular Universal: What about performance, server load?

Tags: angular-universal

I tried to learn about the performance and server load by pre-rendering angular2, I tested for small applications.

I have a question for someone with experience with pre-rendering large applications or online shops? Does pre-rendering is a efficient?